# Drop down menu cuts off or appears behind div

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu which is appearing behind my image transition gallery div. Below is the image of what it looks like and the HTML and CSS for it.

[image]

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="top_bar">
<div id="top_inner">
<div id="logo"> <a href="http://www.edosbornephotography.com"><img src="images/logo.gif" alt="Ed Osborne" width="225" height="115" class="logo"></a></div>
<div class="nav">
<ul class = "menu" >
            <li> <a href = "#" > Home </a> </li>
            <li><a href = "#" > Packages </a>
            <li><a href = "#" > Weddings </a>
            <li><a href = "#" id="left" > Lifestyle </a>
        <ul class = "submenu" >
            <li> <a href = "#" > Families </a> </li>
            <li> <a href = "#"> Newborn/Child </a> </li>
            <li> <a href = "#" > Portraits </a> </li>
        </ul>
        </li>

        <li> <a href = "#" > Blog </a> </li>
        <li><a href = "#" id="left"> Abous Us </a>
        <ul class = "submenu" >
        <li> <a href = "#" > Ed Osborne </a> </li>
        <li> <a href = "#" > Testimonials </a> </li>
        <li> <a href = "#" > FAQs </a> </li>
        </ul>
        </li>

        <li> <a href = "#" > Contact Us </a> </li>
        <li> <a href = "#" > Links </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="main">  

<div id="smart-gallery">
    <a href="images/cubagallery-img-1.jpg">
        <img src="images/cubagallery-img-1.jpg" /></a> 

    <a href="images/cubagallery-img-15.jpg">
        <img src="images/cubagallery-img-15.jpg" /></a> 

    <a href="images/cubagallery-img-3.jpg">
        <img src="images/cubagallery-img-3.jpg" /></a> 

    <a href="images/cubagallery-img-4.jpg"></a>
        <img src="images/cubagallery-img-4.jpg" /></a>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.min-gallery
{
width: 927px;
height: 615px;
border: solid 1px black;
background-color: Black;
background: url(../images/bg.jpg);
margin: auto;
margin-left: 232px;
}

.min-gallery .preview
{
width: 852px;
height: 493px;
margin-top: 36px;
margin-left: 36px;
margin-right: 36px;
position: relative;
border: solid 2px black;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: White;
}

.min-gallery .preview img
{
/* width: 795px;             height: 525px;*/
position: absolute;
}

.min-gallery .bottom
{
width: 100%;
height: 98px;
color: Gray;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: bold;
overflow: hidden;
}

#top_bar {
width: 100%;
height: 145px;
background: #000000;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#top_inner {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1000px;
height: 144px;
}

.nav {
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
padding-top: 100px;
}

ul.menu {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
float: left;
background: #222;
font-size: 1.2em;
background: url(../images/topnav_bg.gif) repeat-x;
}
ul.menu li {
float: left;
margin: 0;  
position: relative; 
}
ul.menu li a{
padding: 10px 18px;
color: #fff;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
float: left;
}

ul.menu li a#left{
padding: 10px 5px;
color: #fff;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
float: left;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
background: url(../images/topnav_hover.gif) no-repeat center top;
}

ul.menu li span { 
width: 11px;
height: 35px;
float: left;
background: url(../images/subnav_btn.gif) no-repeat center top;
}

ul.menu li span.subhover {
background-position: center bottom; cursor: pointer;
}

ul.menu li ul.submenu {
list-style: none;
position: absolute; 
left: 0; top: 35px;
background: #333;
margin: 0; padding: 0;
display: none;
float: left;
width: 170px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #111;
}

ul.menu li ul.submenu li{
margin: 0; padding: 0;
border-top: 1px solid #252525; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #444; 
clear: both;
width: 170px;
}

html ul.menu li ul.submenu li a {
float: left;
width: 122px;
padding-left: 30px;
text-align: left;
}
```

When I remove position:absolute from .min-gallery .preview img, the drop down menu appears on top which is how I want it but the images do stop changing and just stick on one image.

Anyone got a quick fix? Sorry about the pasting of all the code but I dont know how else I can express my point to you guys

Thanks

Comment: Are you setting your z-index correctly? The menu will need to have a z-index higher then the image gallery and not have a position:static (default)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

set the higher  z-index of drop down menu .

```
.submenu { z-index: 999; }
```

reason "An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order."

Comment: @Mark i didn't know that i am on mobile so when i was started tying there were not any answer

Comment: Great answer - helped me alot!

Answer (score 11):

Use a z-index for your drop down menu.

```
.submenu { z-index: 1; }
```

Also, as a side note, if you are using prefixed properties you should also use the spec property as well which should appear last after the vendor specific prefixes. Example:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
```

When a vendor supports the standard property, you don't have to change your code.

Comment: Cheers mate that worked. The value of z-index needed to be higher else it didnt work but thanks man! Life saver

Answer (score 5):

Find the overflow property in the parent or in the child element and remove the overflow property.

You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Use

> .submenu { z-index: 1;position :relative}